# How can I call a taginfo batch script from cvsnt

Tags: tags, cvsnt

I'd like to call a batch-script during a cvs tag operation on a cvsnt server. But everyting I get is "script execution failed". Where is the script I'd like to call supposed to be located or how could I address it with variables?

If I call shell commands directly like "echo something" everything works fine and I also get the additional parameters added by cvsnt like the actual TAG, command and directory. If I want to call a batch either with relative path, without a past or even with ${CVSROOT}/CVSROOT/triggerbuild.cmd everything I get is 'script execution failed'.

My taginfo entries:

```
ALL echo
```

-> results in tag command folder

```
ALL echo ${CVSROOT}/CVSROOT/trigger_release_build.bat
```

-> results in 'script execution failed'.

I want to simply call a batch script that trigger my jenkins server to start a build under some conditions. The trigger script is finished and working fine when executed from a local shell. Only integratino in cvsnt taginfo file doesn't work.

addition: the quoted Code is the overall code causing the failure. The code of the batch file is not relevant because it is not even called due to the error.

This is the documentation from cvsnt's tagfile:

```
# The "taginfo" file is used to control pre-tag checks.
# The filter on the right is invoked with the following arguments:
#
# $1 -- tagname
# $2 -- operation "add" for tag, "mov" for tag -F, and "del" for tag -d
# $3 -- repository
#
# The filter is passed a series of filename/version pairs on its standard     input
#    
# A non-zero exit of the filter program will cause the tag to be aborted.
#
# The first entry on a line is a regular expression which is tested
# against the directory that the change is being committed to, relative
# to the $CVSROOT.  For the first match that is found, then the remainder
# of the line is the name of the filter to run.
#
# If the repository name does not match any of the regular expressions in         this
# file, the "DEFAULT" line is used, if it is specified.
#
# If the name "ALL" appears as a regular expression it is always used
# in addition to the first matching regex or "DEFAULT".
```

When using backslashes I get different error messages about invalid characters \C

Comment: Windows uses back slashes as its directory separator s not forward slashes. Additionally, can you explain what `${CVSROOT}` is? Is it the actual name of a directory? is it supposed to represent a variable in a Windows or is it a variable for a specific utility or scripting language? Please use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58418162/edit) facility to update your question with the required information and a [mcve] of the code you'd like us to help you with. _We need to be able to replicate your issue in order to help you to fix it._

Comment: Do you know what I'm talking about?

Comment: As the batch file is not relevant, I have removed the [[tag:batch-file]] tag attached to your question.

Comment: sorry, 'taginfo' as tag would descripe the problem better but unfortunately I'm not allowed to set it. And 'batch-file' or 'batch-script' imho would descripe the problem more detailled as the prioblem only appears when calling an external script instead of executing internal commands.